# Passing bool to function from feed_dict not work

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to feed_dict value bool to a function

```
def sum(a, b, flag = True, msg1= "Sum", msg2= "Multiply "):

    if (flag is True):
        print(msg1)
        vtotal = tf.add(a,b)
    else:
        print(msg2)
        vtotal = tf.multiply(a,b)

    return vtotal
```

when i call the function as sum(a,b), the default value of flag = True is used for processing

but when i call the function as

```
sum(a, b, flag):
```

and i feed the value of flag from feed_dict like

```
output = sess.run(total,feed_dict = {a: a_arr, b: b_arr, flag: True})
```

it does not take value as True, rather executes the else part of the function

the full code is below: Please help why is this happening.

```
def initialize_placeholders():
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[3,None],name="a")
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[3,None],name ="b")
    flag = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name="flag")

    return a, b, flag

def sum(a, b, flag = True, msg1= "Sum", msg2= "Multiply "):

    if (flag is True):
        print(msg1)
        vtotal = tf.add(a,b)
    else:
        print(msg2)
        vtotal = tf.multiply(a,b)

    return vtotal

def model(a_arr,b_arr):
    #print(a_arr)
    #print(b_arr)
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    a, b ,flag= initialize_placeholders()
    total = sum(a,b,flag)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    print(flag)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        output = sess.run(total,feed_dict = {a: a_arr, b: b_arr, flag: True})
        print(flag)
        unv = sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables())
        sess.close()
    return output, unv

a_arr = np.arange(6)
a_arr = a_arr.reshape(3,2)
b_arr = np.array([2,4,6,8,10,12])
b_arr = b_arr.reshape(3,2)
output , unv = model(a_arr,b_arr)
print(output)
print(unv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use TensorFlow values in regular conditional Python statements (unless you are using something like [AutoGraph](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autograph)). You can do what you want with [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) like this:

```
def sum(a, b, flag=True):
    flag = tf.convert_to_tensor(flag)
    return tf.cond(flag, lambda: tf.add(a, b), lambda: tf.multiply(a, b))
```

You could also make it a bit more complicated in order to save the [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) operation when the value of `flag` is fixed in advance. For example, you could have something like this:

```
def sum(a, b, flag = True, msg1= "Sum", msg2= "Multiply "):
    true_fn = lambda: tf.add(a, b)
    false_fn = lambda: tf.multiply(a, b)
    if flag is True:
        return true_fn()
    elif flag is False:
        return false_fn()
    else:  # Use TensorFlow conditional
        flag = tf.convert_to_tensor(flag)
        return tf.cond(flag, true_fn, false_fn)
```

I removed the `print` instructions because they do cannot be directly used in TensorFlow conditionals, but you can still have [`tf.print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print) operations if you want to see the printed messages when the graph is executed.